# Como puedo resolver problema de conexión e inserción a base de datos DB Browser for SQLite desde Visual Studio 2022, está dando error en insertar más?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, sqlite, sqlite3, visual

Hago depuración paso a paso por instrucciones mostrándome los valores en cada línea y corre hasta `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` y de ahí salta al Catch mostrándome el error que sale en la imagen, Comparto el código de las tablas iniciales:

```
CREATE TABLE TB_Registrarse
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
APLICATION TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
NOMBRES TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
APELLIDOS TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
DIRECCION TEXT(100) NOT NULL,
TELEFONO INT NOT NULL,
EMAIL TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
CONTRASENA TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
REIT_CONTRAS TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
FECHA DATE NOT NULL
);

--Ahora de la tabla TB_InicioSesion

CREATE TABLE TB_InicioSesion
(
ID INT IDENTITY,
EMAIL TEXT(50) NOT NULL,
CONTRASENA TEXT(15) NOT NULL,
FECHA DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

Y el código de VB.Net para insertar los datos:

```
Private Sub btnRegistrarse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegistrarse.Click
    Dim FormInicioSesion As New FormInicioSesion
    Dim APLICATION As String = Me.cboAplicaciones.SelectedItem.ToString()
    Dim NOMBRES As String = Me.txtNombreUser.Text
    Dim APELLIDOS As String = Me.txtApellidoUser.Text
    Dim DIRECCION As String = Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text
    Dim TELEFONO As Int64 = Val(Me.txtPhoneUser.Text)
    Dim EMAIL As String = Me.txtEmailUser.Text
    Dim CONTRASENA As String = Me.txtPass.Text
    Dim REIT_CONTRAS As String = Me.txtPassword.Text
    Dim FECHA As Date = Date.Now
    Dim oportunidades As Integer = 0
    Dim click As ButtonState = ButtonState.Pushed
    ' Verificar si los TextBox están llenos
    'If click = True And oportunidades = 1 And Me.cboAplicaciones.Text = "" Or Me.cboAplicaciones.Text <> "AppESTEMATI" Or Me.txtNombreUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtApellidoUser.Text = "" Or
    '    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPhoneUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPass.Text = "" Or Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    '    MessageBox.Show("Por favor, complete todos los campos antes de registrar.", "Campos vacíos.1ra Oportunidad", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    '    Me.cboAplicaciones.Focus()
    'ElseIf click = True And oportunidades = 2 And Me.cboAplicaciones.Text = "" Or Me.cboAplicaciones.Text <> "AppESTEMATI" Or Me.txtNombreUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtApellidoUser.Text = "" Or
    '    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPhoneUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPass.Text = "" And Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    '    MessageBox.Show("En la 3ra oportunidad el formulario se cerrará.", "2da Oportunidad ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    '    Me.cboAplicaciones.Focus()
    'ElseIf click = True And oportunidades = 3 And Me.cboAplicaciones.Text = "" Or Me.cboAplicaciones.Text <> "AppESTEMATI" Or Me.txtNombreUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtApellidoUser.Text = "" Or
    '    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPhoneUser.Text = "" Or Me.txtPass.Text = "" And Me.txtPassword.Text = "" Then
    '    MessageBox.Show("Se han agotado las oportunidades. El formulario se cerrará.", "Oportunidades agotadas", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    '    Me.Hide()
    '    Me.Close()
    'Else
    Try
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                conn.Open()
            End If
            'Using transaction As SQLiteTransaction = conn.BeginTransaction()
            Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO TB_Registrarse (APLICATION, NOMBRES, APELLIDOS, DIRECCION, TELEFONO, EMAIL, CONTRASENA, REIT_CONTRAS, FECHA) 
                                    VALUES (@APLICATION, @NOMBRES, @APELLIDOS, @DIRECCION, @TELEFONO, @EMAIL, @CONTRASENA, @REIT_CONTRAS, @FECHA)"
            Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(query, conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APLICATION", APLICATION)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOMBRES", NOMBRES)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APELLIDOS", APELLIDOS)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DIRECCION", DIRECCION)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TELEFONO", TELEFONO)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMAIL", EMAIL)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTRASENA", CONTRASENA)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REIT_CONTRAS", REIT_CONTRAS)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FECHA", FECHA)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ' Confirmar la transacción
            '    transaction.Commit()
            'End Using
            If CONTRASENA <> "" And REIT_CONTRAS <> "" And REIT_CONTRAS <> CONTRASENA Then
                MessageBox.Show("Las contraseñas no coinciden. Inténtelo de nuevo.")
                Me.txtPass.Text = ""
                Me.txtPassword.Text = ""
                Me.txtPass.Focus()
                Call validarEmail()
                MsgBox("Date Insert Successfully")
            End If
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Finally
            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                conn.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    'End If
    oportunidades -= 1
    Me.cboAplicaciones.SelectedItem = -1
    Me.txtNombreUser.Clear()
    Me.txtApellidoUser.Clear()
    Me.txtDomicilioUser.Clear()
    Me.txtPhoneUser.Clear()
    Me.txtEmailUser.Clear()
    Me.txtPass.Clear()
    Me.txtPassword.Clear()
    Me.Close()
    Me.Hide()
    Dim formInstalador As New FormInstaladorESTEMATI()
    formInstalador.Show()

End Sub
```

Si alguien puede darme una mano para  resolver el problema, instalé y desinstalé 3 veces DB Browser for SQLite en Descargas, copié y pegué con sus archivos en la carpeta de mi aplicación en C://Users/miUsuario/source/repos/miApp/BaseDeDatos.db; esta ruta configuré en App.config > connectionString, en MyProject > Configuracion, en cabecera de formularios arriba del Load como Public conn As New SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\Users\miUsuario\source\repos\miApp\BaseDeDatos.db"); agregué desde el Administrador de paquetes NuGet System.Data.SQLite, hice todo lo que pude(creo) y sigo con el inconveniente.

Comment: No pusiste el error ni en texto ni imagen.

Comment: javdromero.- En la descripción que hice está detallado el error, especifiqué que al depurar paso a paso pasando por todas las lineas mostrando que están con valores y al llegar al cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() salta al Catch mostrándome el mensaje de error:  code=Constraint[19],message=System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException[0x87AF202F]; constraint failed NOT NULL constraint failed TB_Registrarse.ID; cuando a esta tabla el ID INT IDENTITY,  sin NULL ni NOT NULL, (PARA MI RARO),

Comment: javdromero.- P / D: ADICIONÉ UNA IMAGEN DEL ERROR.

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo del query como tal ya hecho? Viste que efectivamente no envíes valores null y sean del tipo de dato correcto?

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar a mi solicitud, Solucioné el inconveniente Eliminando la Base de datos DB Browser for SQLite e instalandola de nuevo en el Archivo de mi Aplicacion copiando la ruta de mi Proyecto y pegando en el Archivo. Resuelto el problema. Desde ya muchas gracias. Desarrollando Más.-